# Cancel Task.Run job

Tags: vb.net, winforms, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have `async` method as shown below. I would like to have possibility to `cancel` it when user decide to stop the job. How could i do that in new button `CancelUpdate_Click`

```
    Private Async Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
            Await DoWorkAsync()
    End Sub
    
    Private Function DoWorkAsync() As Task(Of List(Of Vals))
                Return _
                    Task.Run(
                        Async Function() _
                                _migrator.PrepareMigration(CInt(Invoke(New Func(Of Integer)(Function() lbNumms.SelectedValue))), CInt(Invoke(New Func(Of Integer)(Function() lbPro.SelectedValue)))))
    End Function
    
Private Sub CancelUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CancelUpdate.Click
            'Stop DoWorkAsync if running
    End Sub
```

**UPDATED:**

```
Private _tokenSource As New CancellationTokenSource()
        Private ReadOnly _token = _tokenSource.Token

Private Async Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
     Try
        Private ReadOnly _tokenSource As New CancellationTokenSource()
    Private ReadOnly _token = _tokenSource.Token
            Await DoWorkAsync()
        Catch oe As OperationCanceledException
                MessageBox.Show("Task has been cancelled")
      Finally
        _tokenSource.Dispose()
      End Try
    End Sub
        
        Private Function DoWorkAsync() As Task(Of List(Of Vals))
                    Return _
                        Task.Run(
                            Function()
                                Dim tokenSource = New CancellationTokenSource()
                                Dim token = tokenSource.Token
                                Return _migrator.PrepareMigration(CInt(Invoke(New Func(Of Integer)(Function() lbNumms.SelectedValue))), CInt(Invoke(New Func(Of Integer)(Function() lbProducent.SelectedValue))), _token)
                            End Function)
        End Function
            
        
        Public Function PrepareMigration(value1 As Integer, value2 As Integer, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As List(Of Vals))
        
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() 
        MethodA()
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
        MethodB()
        
        End Function
        
        Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
                      _tokenSource.Cancel()
        End Sub
```

Comment: Use another overloading of `Task.Run`, which takes `CancelationToken` as second parameter.

Comment: @Rekshino That only works if it hasn't started yet.

Comment: Re updated code, you're creating a new token source inside the lambda sent to `Task.Run`, that won't work because the outside code can't access it.  You should just reference `_tokenSource` in the lambda.  The code for `PrepareMigration` looks like what I was suggesting.

Comment: @Craig I saw it and corrected you right, besides all looks fine?

Comment: Otherwise, nothing that jumps out at me as obviously wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cancellation isn't something that just magically works.  It has to be explicitly coded.  In this case, your `PrepareMigration` routine needs to take a `CancellationToken` parameter **and** needs to periodically check to see if that parameter's `IsCancellationRequested` property has been set to `True`.

One shortcut for doing this is to periodically call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` on the token; this will result in an `OperationCanceledException` if the property is set.

If you are working in a routine that returns a `Task`, you can return `Task.FromCanceled`.

You would get the `CancellationToken` to pass in from a `CancellationTokenSource`.  Then the event handler for the cancel button would call `Cancel` on the source to signal the issued token.

For example, if you have processing that involves multiple steps, maybe it would work like this:

```vb
'Include other parameters as appropriate.
Sub PrepareMigration(ByVal token As CancellationToken)
    DoStep1()

    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
    DoStep2()

    '...

    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
    DoStepn()
End Sub
```

Or, if you have something where you are processing a set of items, maybe it would look like this:

```vb
Sub PrepareMigration(ByVal token As CancellationToken)
    For Each item In itemsToProcess
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
        DoTheItem(item)
    Next
End Sub
```

Mix and match as required.  If a routine called in a particular step is especially long-running, that routine itself might need to be cancellation-aware.

Ultimately, where you put checks depends on the details of the steps of your calculation (including potentially "quick" vs "slow" steps) and what limits you want to set on how long a user has to wait until a requested cancellation takes effect.

Comment: @Arie see my edit.

Comment: can u post any example? In PrepareMigration method i got call to few methods in order to be execute like: StartProcess() then GetData() should i just check iscancelation befire each call to those methods inside PrepareMigration or?

Comment: @Arie It's up to you when you think it makes sense to check for cancellation.  Maybe before each call to these methods.  Maybe the methods themselves need to be cancellation-aware.  It depends on how long each processing step might take and what limit you want to set on how long the user has to wait for a requested cancel to take effect.

Comment: You might be able to do something along those lines where you put steps into a list of e.g. `Action`, then iterated over the list alternating execution and cancellation check.  It would be a little complicated and tricky for a later observer to follow.

Comment: I updated main post (section UPDATED) can u check if the way i did looks fine? As i can see it works ... But would like to make sure if its really ok - can u just take a look on that plz?